# Have got an error with a max

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;

import java.util.Scanner;

class apples {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Random rand = new Random();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int freq[] = new int[7];

    for (int roll=1;roll<=10000;roll++){

        ++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)];

    }

    System.out.println("So much money at stake,make a right decision!\nWhat are betting on?");

    int input= sc.nextInt();

    int comparison=max(freq[1],freq[2],freq[3],freq[4],freq[5],freq[6],freq[7]);

    if(input==comparison){

        System.out.println("You won");

    }else {

        System.out.println("Whoops,you lost all your money");

    }

}

private static int max(int i, int j, int k, int l, int m, int n, int o) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: post error output please

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your call to `max` is incorrect.  Arrays in Java are 0-indexed which means it should be: `int comparison=max(freq[0],  freq[1], freq[2], freq[3], freq[4], freq[5], freq[6]);` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `freq[7]` will give you `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since your array only has 7 elements, having indices from 0 to 6.

Beside that, it makes no sense to pass the array elements as separate arguments to the `max` method. Just pass the entire array in a single argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you tell me please how am i able to pass the entire array in a single argument? What kind of code would it be?

Comment: @ИгорьПроценко hmm, `int comparison=max(freq)`.

Comment: Thanks,and the last question. It's supposed to give you a message "You won" when you guessed the element with biggest number,but somehow,it constantly gives me the message "You lost"  even if you gave the right answer. Did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` which means that you trying to get element from index that is greater than your array size.
So, use

```
int comparison=max(freq[0],freq[1],freq[2],freq[3],freq[4],freq[5],freq[6]);
```

instead of

```
int comparison=max(freq[1],freq[2],freq[3],freq[4],freq[5],freq[6],freq[7]);
```

Because in JAVA indexes begin from **0** not **1**!

Answer (score -2):

Please make your post a question, not just an empty method.  Below code could be used for finding the max:

```
int max = i;
if (j > max)
    max = j;
if (k > max)
    max = k;
if (l > max)
    max = l;
if (m > max)
    max = m;
if (n > max)
    max = n;
if (o > max)
    max = o;
return max;
```

Comment: I think passing an `Array` and than iterate over it will be better solution.

Comment: Definitely more generic, I was thinking maybe there was a method signature requirement but maybe not.